# Windows VM does not start in VMware Fusion after cloning old Mac to new hardware

Tags: macos, virtualization, vmware

I had an old Mac with Sierra installed. Its screen got bad and I bought a new one with Sierra.

After cloning my old device into new hardware, my Windows VM in VMware Fusion is not working. It mentions " <⁣user folder>/<⁣directory for Windows VM files>/.Windows 7 x64-disk1.vmdk cannot be opened or some dependent files can not be opened". It also says something like disk power on failed.

Comment: after deleting " <⁣user folder>/<⁣directory for Windows VM files>/Windows 7 x64-disk1.vmdk.lck" the VM started working.

Answer (score 1):

After deleting "<⁣user folder>/<⁣directory for Windows VM files>/Windows 7 x64-disk1.vmdk.lck" the VM started working.